# Call web2py service from other web2py service

Tags: web2py

I have a controller where I have numerous services. In some cases I want to call one service from other one. Something like this:

```
@service.json
@service.jsonrpc
def addme(text,localeid=1):
    return db.mes.insert(me=text,locale=localeid)



@service.json
@service.jsonrpc
def addexmelink(exidentifier,metext):
    meidentifier=addme(metext)
    return db.exmelinker.insert(meid=meidentifier,exid=exidentifier)
```

I tried this but its not working. I get this error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. But I have also observed that `addme` is getting called and record is getting inserted but it returns data whose data type is `Reference` and it is causing some problem.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you explain how you are calling the functions and what is happening (e.g., is there an exception)?

Comment: @Anthony: I just edited the question to include original service code.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? What happens if you do `db.exmelinker.insert(meid=long(meidentifier), exid=exidentifier)`? Does it work if you call these functions from the shell rather than via RPC?

Comment: @Anthony: It worked when I did this : return long(db.exmelinker.insert(meid=meidentifier,exid=exidentifier))

Comment: I see, the problem was that `addexmelink` was returning a `Reference`, not that `addme` was. In any case, I don't think that should be a problem -- the `Reference` object shouldn't cause any problems for the JSON serializer. I would still be interested to see the full traceback (and the method by which this is called) to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I did this after Anthony's suggestion:

```
@service.json
@service.jsonrpc
def addexmelink(exidentifier,metext):
    meidentifier=addme(metext)
    return long(db.exmelinker.insert(meid=meidentifier,exid=exidentifier))
```